# How to decode base64 response?

Tags: web3.js, instructions, deserialization, decode

**Req:**

```
{
    "method": "getMultipleAccounts",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": [
        [
            "EgC7JMiqh9eVETBvYdzKuKyo4RoxzrDV1ncpXLYJqjmA"
        ],
        {
            "encoding": "base64",
            "commitment": "processed"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Res:**

```
"value": [
            {
                "data": [
                    "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",
                    "base64"
                ],
                "executable": false,
                "lamports": 4906800,
                "owner": "CMZYPASGWeTz7RNGHaRJfCq2XQ5pYK6nDvVQxzkH51zb",
                "rentEpoch": 0,
                "space": 577
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean decoding the base 64 account data into something more understandable, like JSON.

It depends on your program! Programs write bytes into accounts however they want. For example, the SPL token program writes mint information into 82 bytes, and account information into 165 bytes. If you see that an account is 82 bytes, then you can interpret those bytes as though they were a mint, so the first 36 bytes contain the mint authority (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/c8b42ed7c5e5ba1c74dd9ddb4bc22a8e1bf5602e/token/program/src/state.rs#L18)

So for the program you're querying, you'll need to know how they serialize accounts. You can get this information from an IDL or a client library.